# Why is that when defining the exterior derivative, there is no consideration of parallel transport?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

When we define the connection, we have to specify the connection coefficients for generalizing the directional derivative for a general $(p,q)$ tensor. However, when defining a derivative for antisymmetric tensors, we can directly define an exterior derivative without any consideration of parallel transport or how we subtract objects existing in two different tangent spaces.

Why is this?

Comment: There is, to my knowledge, no notion of parallel transport associated to the exterior derivative. There's no need to specify connection coefficients because the exterior derivative $d$ is not a connection, nor can it be canonically associated to one.

Comment: @Kajelad We still have a notion of taking derivative of a vector somewhere. When we do exterior derivative of a one form, we are indirectly doing it for the associative vector. So, I thought naturally here some sort of parallel transport would come up because we are subtracting vectors which exist in different places @

Comment: @Kajelad Does your $\iota_V$ refer to the interior product? If so, then it is $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear in $V$ because differential forms are $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear in their arguments ($\iota_{fV}(\eta)= \eta(fV,\cdots)=f\eta(V,\cdots)=f\iota_V(\eta)$)

Comment: @peek-a-boo You're right; I was thinking of the Lie derivative $\iota_V(d\omega)+d(\iota_V\omega)$. For parallel transport to be well defined, we need both a well-defined notion of "differentiating along a curve" and unique solutions of the corresponding ODE. $\iota_{\dot{\gamma}}(d\omega)$ has the former property, but not the latter.

Comment: Differential forms are anti symmeteric tensor, so since covariant derivative is defined for tensor, I am pretty sure the exterior derivative could be built up from it. I have seen somewhat similar ideas in final chap of Tristan Needham where he develops higher forms using directioncal derivatives.

Comment: The exercise you want here is this: If $\nabla$ is a torsion-free connection (e.g., the Levi-Civita connection), then for a $1$-form $\phi$ we have $$d\phi(X,Y) = (\nabla\phi)(X,Y) - (\nabla\phi)(Y,X).$$

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector bundle $E\to X$ and a connection $\nabla$ on $E$, the covariant derivative is an operator
$$\nabla: \Gamma(E)\to \Omega^1(X)\otimes \Gamma(E).$$
This operator is the first one of a sequence of operators
$$d^\nabla:\Omega^k(X)\otimes \Gamma(E)\to \Omega^{k+1}(X)\otimes \Gamma(E)$$
for a definition see my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409645/conceptual-definition-of-the-extension-of-a-connection-to-1-forms/409703#409703).

Now, let $E = X\times \mathbb R \to X$, the trivial line bundle of $X$, and choose as $\nabla$ the trivial (flat) connection (so the coefficient(s) will be zero in the natural trivialization of $E$), then $d^\nabla = d$ the exterior differential.

Comment: Thank u... but I was completly lost as soon as you put the gradient on top of the d